# Include the request URI in catalina.out?

Tags: logging, tomcat, log-files, tomcat7

Running Tomcat 7. I have errors in catalina.out that I can't troubleshoot because I'm not sure which web request is causing them. Is there any way to capture more details about a given exception (ideally the URL and the time) so that I can do a better job of troubleshooting them?

Answer (score 1):

Configure the access log valve: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Logging. With it you can log not only the URI but also the thread that handled the erroneus request, which ought to help you correlate access log entries with stacktraces in catalina.out.

Comment: I'll give it a try! If it works I'll accept this answer.